# Opennebula Virtual Machine localhost login

Tags: opennebula

Following this [Opennebula quickstart guide on Ubuntu 12.04](http://docs.opennebula.org/pdf/4.4/opennebula_4.4_qs_ubuntu_kvm_guide.pdf), I was able to create and instantiate a CentOS 6.4 virtual machine. However, I don't know what login credentials to use (i.e. username and password) to remotely access the vm. I can ping the vm and onevm list command is saying it's running. I've already tried oneadmin and the password inside ~/.one/one_auth file but it's not working. I also tried root with no password, and oneadmin with opennebula as password. But still, it's not working. Here's a snapshot of the VM created: [image]

Apologies if the question is too simple. It's just that I don't see any username/password to be used or to be set on the guide, for the virtual machine created.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you follow http://opennebula.org/documentation:archives:rel3.0:ignc ?

Comment: @nrathaus Yes, I did and I'm pretty sure I've already added the id_rsa.pub to the authorized keys. I don't know why am I still prompted for password. Is IP conflict a possible cause here?

Comment: You know that id_rsa.pbu is for logging via SSH not console, right?

Comment: @nrathaus yes i do. I tried to SSH using oneadmin and oneuser username but I am required with a password

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have followed the steps in the [quickstart guide](http://docs.opennebula.org/stable/design_and_installation/quick_starts/qs_centos_kvm.html#adding-virtual-resources):

- specifying the --ssh in the onetemplate create command

  ```
  $ onetemplate create --name "CentOS-6.4" --cpu 1 --vcpu 1 --memory 512 \
  --arch x86_64 --disk "CentOS-6.4_x86_64" --nic "private" --vnc \
  --ssh
  ```
- including your ssh public key in the user template using:

  ```
  $ EDITOR=vi oneuser update oneadmin
  SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBANBWTQmm4Gt..."
  ```

You have to ssh **as root** using your ssh key. You can retrieve the IP of the VM using the onevm command and the ID returned by the onetemplate instantiate command.